# prevent Dropbox or any apps show on UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios

I'm using UIDocumentInteractionController to show a menu "Open in...".
But i don't want any apps appear on this menu.
How to do that?
Thanks so much.

Comment: The point of the "Open In" menu is to show other apps. What do you wish to show?

Comment: i want some apps don't show.example i want to ignore Evernote,but it always show.how to do that?

Comment: You either get all apps or no apps. There is no way to get only specific apps.